# How to let NSTextField grow with the text in auto layout?

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, autolayout

Auto layout in Lion should make it fairly simple to let a text field (and hence a label) grow with text it holds.

The text field is set to wrap in Interface Builder.

What is a simple and reliable way to do this?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The method `intrinsicContentSize` in `NSView` returns what the view itself thinks of as its intrinsic content size.

`NSTextField` calculates this without considering the `wraps` property of its cell, so it will report the dimensions of the text if laid out in on a single line.

Hence, a custom subclass of `NSTextField` can override this method to return a better value, such as the one provided by the cell's `cellSizeForBounds:` method:

```
-(NSSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    if ( ![self.cell wraps] ) {
        return [super intrinsicContentSize];
    }

    NSRect frame = [self frame];

    CGFloat width = frame.size.width;

    // Make the frame very high, while keeping the width
    frame.size.height = CGFLOAT_MAX;

    // Calculate new height within the frame
    // with practically infinite height.
    CGFloat height = [self.cell cellSizeForBounds: frame].height;

    return NSMakeSize(width, height);
}

// you need to invalidate the layout on text change, else it wouldn't grow by changing the text
- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [super textDidChange:notification];
    [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
}
```

Comment: This exactly matches what I am seeing. Just to clarify, this ignoring of the 'wraps' property on the cell appears to be a bug in Lion which has been fixed in Mountain Lion. So, if you are targeting Lion and above you will see different results in the 2 OSes until you apply the bugfix to bring Lion up to speed.

Comment: Yes, this is a bug in Lion. I really wish Apple would fix these issues in both OS X 10.7 && 10.8. In my implementation, I do some more checks for special cases (e.g. If it is Lion || If language is not English) and I set my height a little different. Nevertheless, what Monolo posted is a good start.

Comment: The intrinsicContentSize: method is not called when you change the text in it by setStringValue:.

Comment: you need to invalidate the layout on - (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [super textDidChange:notification];
    [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
}

Comment: Has anyone made a Swift version of this lately?

Comment: Thank you for this answer Peter, it did exactly what I needed and very elegantly via the intrinsic size. I am using Cocoa Bindings and using your method solves a number of headaches automatically! I have included a Swift 4 version below.

Answer (score 9):

### Swift 4

### Editable Autosizing NSTextField

*Based on Peter Lapisu's Objective-C post*

Subclass `NSTextField`, add the code below.

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: NSSize {
    // Guard the cell exists and wraps
    guard let cell = self.cell, cell.wraps else {return super.intrinsicContentSize}

    // Use intrinsic width to jive with autolayout
    let width = super.intrinsicContentSize.width

    // Set the frame height to a reasonable number
    self.frame.size.height = 750.0

    // Calcuate height
    let height = cell.cellSize(forBounds: self.frame).height

    return NSMakeSize(width, height);
}

override func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    super.textDidChange(notification)
    super.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
}
```

Setting `self.frame.size.height` to 'a reasonable number' **avoids** some bugs when using `FLT_MAX`, `CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude` or large numbers. The bugs occur during operation when the user select highlights the text in the field, they can drag scroll up and down off into infinity. Additionally when the user enters text the `NSTextField` is blanked out until the user ends editing. Finally if the user has selected the `NSTextField` and then attempts to resize the window, if the value of `self.frame.size.height` is too large the window will hang.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is based on manipulating `intrinsicContentSize` but that may not be necessary in all cases. Autolayout will grow and shrink the height of the text field if (a) you give the text field a `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` and (b) make the field not `editable`. These steps enable the text field to determine its intrinsic width and calculate the height needed for autolayout. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29547238/1940455) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25926579/1940455) for more details.

Even more obscurely, it follows from the dependency on the text field's `editable` attribute that autolayout will break if you are using bindings on the field and fail to clear the `Conditionally Sets Editable` option.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. It's these little things that causing making the jump from iOS to Mac frustrating.