# getting a NSTextField to grow with the text in auto layout?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield, autolayout

I'm trying to get my NSTextField to have its height grow (much like in iChat or Adium) once the user types enough text to overflow the width of the control (as asked [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463680/how-to-let-nstextfield-grow-with-the-text-in-auto-layout))

I've implimented the accepted answer yet I can't seem to get it to work.  I have uploaded my attempt at http://scottyob.com/pub/autoGrowingExample.zip

Ideally, when the text grows, the containing window should grow with it, but I'm trying baby steps here.

Comment: Just a suggestion, do you think it would be easier if you used NSTextView instead?

Comment: What do you mean by “I can't seem to get it to work”? What happens instead? And are you running Lion or Mountain Lion?

Comment: Just tried it on Lion. It works (thanks to the subclass you borrowed from the previous question), but only when the user hits Enter or ends editing. I tried turning on Continuous, but that didn't help.

Comment: That's the same thing that's happening to me @PeterHosey.  It's close, but doesn't have the effect I need

Comment: Anybody know how to do this with `NSTextView`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Solved it! (Inspired by https://github.com/jerrykrinock/CategoriesObjC/blob/master/NS(Attributed)String%2BGeometrics/NS(Attributed)String%2BGeometrics.m )

Reading the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/TextLayout.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000158-SW1) is usually helpful. Apple has engineered all this text layout stuff to be powerful enough to handle all sorts of [complicated edge cases](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextStorageLayer/Tasks/Region.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000925-CJBBIAAF) which is sometimes extremely helpful, and sometimes not.

Firstly, I set the text field to wrap lines on word break, so we actually get multiple lines. (Your example code even had an if statement so it did nothing at all when wrapping was turned off).

The trick to this one was to note that when text is being edited, it’s printed by a ‘field editor’ – a heavy weight `NSTextView` object, owned by an `NSWindow`, that’s reused by whatever `NSTextField` is currently the ‘first responder’ (selected). The `NSTextView` has a single `NSTextContainer` (rectangle where text goes), which has a `NSLayoutManager` to layout the text. We can ask the layout manager how much space it wants to use up, to get the new height of our text field.

The other trick was to override the `NSText` delegate method `- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification` to invalidate the intrinsic content size when the text is changed (so it doesn’t just wait to update when you commit changed by pressing return).

The reason I didn’t use `cellSizeForBounds` as you originally suggested was I couldn’t solve your problem – even when invalidating the intrinsic content size of the cell, `cellSizeForBounds:` continued to return the old size.

Find the example project on [GitHub](https://github.com/DouglasHeriot/AutoGrowingNSTextField).

```
@interface TSTTextGrowth()
{
    BOOL _hasLastIntrinsicSize;
    BOOL _isEditing;
    NSSize _lastIntrinsicSize;
}

@end

@implementation TSTTextGrowth

- (void)textDidBeginEditing:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [super textDidBeginEditing:notification];
    _isEditing = YES;
}

- (void)textDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [super textDidEndEditing:notification];
    _isEditing = NO;
}

- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [super textDidChange:notification];
    [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
}

-(NSSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    NSSize intrinsicSize = _lastIntrinsicSize;

    // Only update the size if we’re editing the text, or if we’ve not set it yet
    // If we try and update it while another text field is selected, it may shrink back down to only the size of one line (for some reason?)
    if(_isEditing || !_hasLastIntrinsicSize)
    {
        intrinsicSize = [super intrinsicContentSize];

        // If we’re being edited, get the shared NSTextView field editor, so we can get more info
        NSText *fieldEditor = [self.window fieldEditor:NO forObject:self];
        if([fieldEditor isKindOfClass:[NSTextView class]])
        {
            NSTextView *textView = (NSTextView *)fieldEditor;
            NSRect usedRect = [textView.textContainer.layoutManager usedRectForTextContainer:textView.textContainer];

            usedRect.size.height += 5.0; // magic number! (the field editor TextView is offset within the NSTextField. It’s easy to get the space above (it’s origin), but it’s difficult to get the default spacing for the bottom, as we may be changing the height

            intrinsicSize.height = usedRect.size.height;
        }

        _lastIntrinsicSize = intrinsicSize;
        _hasLastIntrinsicSize = YES;
    }

    return intrinsicSize;
}

@end
```

As a last note, I’ve never actually used auto layout myself – the demos look amazing, but whenever I actually try it myself, I can’t get it to work quite right and it makes things more complicated. However, in this case, I think it actually did save a bunch of work – without it, `-intrinsicContentSize` wouldn’t exist, and you’d possibly have to set the frame yourself, calculating the new origin as well as the new size (not too difficult, but just more code).

Comment: Seems like we don't need to invalidate intrinsic content size unconditionally - [sample code](https://github.com/billibala/TextFieldExpansion/blob/master/TextFieldExpansion/MyTextField.m#L72)

Comment: this is the greatest solution of all time. thank you.

Comment: While this solution works, there's one problem: the text field always starts out with a height of a single line, even if the text spans multiple lines. Only when you first edit the text, is the height properly adjusted. Does anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: I ran into that problem when trying to apply this solution here to an `NSTokenField` that inherits from `NSTextField`. Take a look at [the super simple alternative I came up with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107385/getting-a-nstextfield-to-grow-with-the-text-in-auto-layout/71585473#71585473)

Answer (score 7):

The solution by DouglasHeriot only works for fixed width text fields. In my app, I have text fields that I want to grow both horizontally and vertically. Therefore I modified the solution as follows:

**AutosizingTextField.h**

```
@interface AutosizingTextField : NSTextField {
    BOOL isEditing;
}
@end
```

**AutosizingTextField.m**

```
@implementation AutosizingTextField

- (void)textDidBeginEditing:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [super textDidBeginEditing:notification];
    isEditing = YES;
}

- (void)textDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [super textDidEndEditing:notification];
    isEditing = NO;
}

- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [super textDidChange:notification];
    [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
}

-(NSSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    if(isEditing)
    {
        NSText *fieldEditor = [self.window fieldEditor:NO forObject:self];
        if(fieldEditor)
        {
            NSTextFieldCell *cellCopy = [self.cell copy];
            cellCopy.stringValue = fieldEditor.string;
            return [cellCopy cellSize];
        }
    }
    return [self.cell cellSize];
}
@end
```

There's a minor issue remaining: When typing spaces, the text jumps a bit to the left. However, that's not a problem in my app, because the text fields shouldn't contain spaces in most cases.

Comment: The computation works well. How do you plan to get the `cellSize` now that the `cell` property of `NSControl` is deprecated in 10.11?

Comment: You can solve the problem of the text shifting to the left by calling `-invalidateTextContainerOrigin` on the field editor. I call `[self.currentEditor invalidateTextContainerOrigin;` in `-setFrame:` and `setFrameSize:` *before* calling super in my NSTextField subclass.

Answer (score 6):

The solution of DouglasHeriot works great for me.

Here is the same code on Swift 4

```
class GrowingTextField: NSTextField {

    var editing = false
    var lastIntrinsicSize = NSSize.zero
    var hasLastIntrinsicSize = false

    override func textDidBeginEditing(_ notification: Notification) {
        super.textDidBeginEditing(notification)
        editing = true
    }

    override func textDidEndEditing(_ notification: Notification) {
        super.textDidEndEditing(notification)
        editing = false
    }

    override func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        super.textDidChange(notification)
        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: NSSize {
        get {
            var intrinsicSize = lastIntrinsicSize

            if editing || !hasLastIntrinsicSize {

                intrinsicSize = super.intrinsicContentSize

                // If we’re being edited, get the shared NSTextView field editor, so we can get more info
                if let textView = self.window?.fieldEditor(false, for: self) as? NSTextView, let textContainer = textView.textContainer, var usedRect = textView.textContainer?.layoutManager?.usedRect(for: textContainer) {
                    usedRect.size.height += 5.0 // magic number! (the field editor TextView is offset within the NSTextField. It’s easy to get the space above (it’s origin), but it’s difficult to get the default spacing for the bottom, as we may be changing the height
                    intrinsicSize.height = usedRect.size.height
                }

                lastIntrinsicSize = intrinsicSize
                hasLastIntrinsicSize = true
            }

            return intrinsicSize
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This solution also works when setting the string value of the text field and when it's resized by AutoLayout. It just uses the attributed text property to calculate the intrinsic content size whenever it's needed.

```
class AutoGrowingTextField: NSTextField {
    var maximumHeight: CGFloat = 100

    override var intrinsicContentSize: NSSize {
        let height = attributedStringValue.boundingRect(
            with: NSSize(width: bounds.width - 8, height: maximumHeight),
            options: [NSString.DrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin]
            ).height + 5

        return NSSize(width: NSView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: height)
    }

    override func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        super.textDidChange(notification)
        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }

    override func layout() {
        super.layout()
        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is working on macOS big Sur while the NSLayoutManager solution is not working there at all. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to limit the size of the TextField (e.g.):

```
if (intrinsicSize.height > 100) 
{
    intrinsicSize = _lastIntrinsicSize;
} 
else
{
    _lastIntrinsicSize = intrinsicSize;
    _hasLastIntrinsicSize = YES;
}
```

([Diff](https://github.com/aral/AutoGrowingNSTextField/commit/dd3523cfbbdbdb64e1d651888b5ea6be376d3a82))

One thing I’m having trouble with is getting the NSTextField embedded in an NSScrollView and having it work properly (especially within an NSStackView). Going to look at whether it wouldn’t be easier with NSTextView instead.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an alternative solution that works well for me:

```
- (NSSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    return [self sizeThatFits:NSMakeSize(self.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
}

- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [super textDidChange:notification];
    [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
}
```

Basically we're just constraining the width to the given width of the element and based on that calculate the fitting height.