# How to implement a multiline NSTokenField?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstokenfield

I want to implement an `NSTokenField` that spans multiple lines. For example:

[Multi-line NSTokenField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voZOn.png)

I found a some sample code of multi-line `NSTokenField` on the internet:

```
IBOutlet NSTokenField *tokenField;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [[tokenField cell] setWraps:YES];
}
```

made my class delegate of the `NSTokenField` and implement the following method

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj {    
    NSRect oldTokenFieldFrame = [tokenField frame];
    NSRect tokenFieldBounds = [tokenField bounds];

    float height = oldTokenFieldFrame.size.height;
    tokenFieldBounds.size.height = CGFLOAT_MAX;
    NSSize cellSize = [[tokenField cell] cellSizeForBounds:tokenFieldBounds];

    float y = oldTokenFieldFrame.origin.y + height - cellSize.height;

    [tokenField setFrame:NSMakeRect(oldTokenFieldFrame.origin.x,
                                          y,
                                          oldTokenFieldFrame.size.width,
                                          cellSize.height)];
}
```

but this code does not work correctly.

Could you please help me with this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `NSTokenField` is a subclass of `NSTextField`. See [getting a NSTextField to grow with the text in auto layout?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14107385/4244136)

Comment: @Willeke thank you so much for the proposed solution. But this solution works if the `NSTextField` is selected. If the `NSTextField` doesn't selected and I will change the window size or try add the text by using drug and drop the height of NSTextField will not grow (resize). Do you have any ideas on this case?

Answer (score 1):

For everybody who is just looking for an answer with working code, I've found this super short solution. Here we go:

```
#import "MyExpandingTokenField.h"

@implementation MyExpandingTokenField

- (NSSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    NSSize intrinsicContentSize = [self sizeThatFits:NSMakeSize(self.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
    intrinsicContentSize = NSMakeSize(intrinsicContentSize.width, intrinsicContentSize.height + 5);
    return intrinsicContentSize;
}

- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [super textDidChange:notification];
    [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
}

@end
```