# Extra blank space when NSTextField is in editing mode

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextfield, nstextview

I made an `NSTextField` subclass which adjusts its width with its content length. The idea (of overriding `intrinsicContentSize`) is from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107385/getting-a-nstextfield-to-grow-with-the-text-in-auto-layout).

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: NSSize {
    if isEditing {
        if let fieldEditor =
            self.window?.fieldEditor(false, for: self) as?
                NSTextView
        {
            let rect = fieldEditor.layoutManager!.usedRect(
                for: fieldEditor.textContainer!
            )

            let size = rect.size

            return size
        }
    }

    let size = self.cell!.cellSize
    return size
}
```

However, there's an extra blank area after the last character. If I set the `size.width` manually (`size.width -= 3.5`, for example), the text will offset back and forth (horizontally) during editing.

I don't see this quirk in macOS's Finder when renaming its sidebar items. How to get rid of the extra space without making the text "jumping"?

[image: extra space after text]

### Update 1:

I added [a demo on GitHub](https://github.com/liushigit/TextFieldDemo).

### Update 2:

Tried setting [`NSTextView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextview)'s [textContainerInset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextview/1449168-textcontainerinset) to a size of 0, 0, which doesn't solve the problem.

### Update 3:

Updated [the repo](https://github.com/liushigit/TextFieldDemo) with @Михаил Масло 's answer. The text still jiggles during editing. The original implementation can be viewed by checking out the initial commit.

Comment: I tried your code (implemented my own `isEditing`) but I see lack of space at top, left and bottom.

Comment: Hi @Willeke, thank you! Mine is in a source list. I've put a demo [here on github](https://github.com/liushigit/TextFieldDemo) I also saw the effect you mentioned. A magic `size.height += 5.0` will fix it partially. You can see in my demo, besides the issue being discussed, a dot is added if you press the spacebar a few times when editing.

Comment: The appended period may be related to this http://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/12/19/how-to-stop-your-mac-from-inserting-a-period-when-you-double-press-the-space-bar/

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate size of the string with defined font directly try this (I've used your code in `TableTextField.swift`):

```
class TableTextField: NSTextField {
  ...
  override var intrinsicContentSize: NSSize {
    return stringValue.size(withConstraintedHeight: 1000, font: fieldEditor.font!)
  }
  ...
}


extension String {
  func size(withConstraintedHeight height: CGFloat, font: NSFont) -> CGSize {
    let constraintRect = CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height)
    let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                        attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font], context: nil)
    let size = boundingBox.size
    return CGSize(width: size.width + 0.5, height: size.height)
  }
}
```

I didn't tend to make it safe so probably you can make it better and exclude force-unwrap and following errors

Comment: Hi thanks! I tried your answer and updated the repo. This is still not a perfect solution since the text will jiggle a little bit during editing. I extended `NSAttributedString` since the `boundingRect(with:)` method of `NSString` is deprecated.

Comment: @LShi I changed text calculator in the following way return `CGSize(width: size.width + 1.0, height: size.height)` and intrinsicContentSize: `return attributedStringValue.size(withConstrainedHeight: 1000, font: font!)`. After it I didn't notice any shrinking

Comment: Hi! not shrinking. Will the text jiggle when you add more characters or simply add trailing spaces?

Comment: @LShi With usual characters it works ok but with trailing spaces - yeah there are some problems. I didn't noticed it when've tested the code. So I can only say the problem not in size now (it's correct) but in something that makes this strange text offset. I experimented a bit and found that `alignmentRectInsets` has offsets 2 from both sides. If you play around this values and additional width in size function you will get not jiggle smooth text. I tried `NSEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 2.5, bottom: 0, right: 2.5)` for `alignmentRectInsets` and `1.5 additional space for size func` and it worked!

Comment: Yes, even the usual characters cause a weak "offset effect".

Comment: Thanks! I will try it and comment later.

Comment: Hi Михаил, I tried your `alignmentRectInsets` idea, the jiggling is gone when `left` and `right` are both set to `4.0` on my machine. However the extra blank space is still there, which means it's not better than my original implementation.