# Auto-resizing NSTokenField with constraint-based layout

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstokenfield

Is there any way to automatically resize the **height** of a NSTokenField (keeping the width constant) using constraints?

`-sizeToFit` should work, but it doesn't. If I set a constraint to keep the width constant and call this method it ignores the constraints and resizes the width only (when what I want is to resize the height only).

Answer (score 1):

Based on [How to let NSTextField grow with the text in auto layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463680/how-to-let-nstextfield-grow-with-the-text-in-auto-layout)

Also don't set size contraints, just let it be.

The method `intrinsicContentSize` in `NSView` returns what the view itself thinks of as its intrinsic content size.

`NSTextField` calculates this without considering the `wraps` property of its cell, so it will report the dimensions of the text if laid out in on a single line.

Hence, a custom subclass of `NSTokenField` can override this method to return a better value, such as the one provided by the cell's `cellSizeForBounds:` method:

```
-(NSSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    if ( ![self.cell wraps] ) {
        return [super intrinsicContentSize];
    }

    NSRect frame = [self frame];

    CGFloat width = frame.size.width;

    // Make the frame very high, while keeping the width
    frame.size.height = CGFLOAT_MAX;

    // Calculate new height within the frame
    // with practically infinite height.
    CGFloat height = [self.cell cellSizeForBounds: frame].height;

    return NSMakeSize(width, height);
}
```

Comment: not quite, the cellSizeForBounds returns always the same size in tokenfield... also you have to listen on textDidChange and invalidateIntrinsicContentSize

Comment: @PeterLapisu cellSizeForBounds does not always return the same size, at least on 10.11. I've posted an answer with the full code.

Answer (score 1):

The `cellSizeForBounds` method of the token field does return the correct size, so you can implement it like this (custom subclass, in Swift):

```
class TagsTokenField: NSTokenField {

    override func textDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
        super.textDidChange(notification)
        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: NSSize {
        let size = self.cell!.cellSizeForBounds(NSMakeRect(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, 1000))
        return NSMakeSize(CGFloat(FLT_MAX), size.height)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Needing an `NSTokenField` with a given width that dynamically grows in height when adding tokens, as well as is displayed with the right size when initialized not empty, I came up with the following super simple solution that works flawless for me:

```
- (NSSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    return [self sizeThatFits:NSMakeSize(self.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
}

- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [super textDidChange:notification];
    [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
}
```

Because for some reason when the intrinsic content size of the `NSTokenField` is always calculated for a single line with unlimited width, we are constraining the width here to it's actual width. Guess we are lucky that `sizeThatFits:` works correctly.