# Accurately get size of wrapping NSTextField (Swift)

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstableview, nstextfield

I need to accurately calculate the size of an NSTextField (because I need that value to calculate the height of the NSTableView's row in which the NSTextField sits). I have a rough approximation now, but it seems off (and I don't want to hard-code fudge it...).

My approximation involves creating a temporary cell, adding the appropriate text to it, and then calculating the height based on that text:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, heightOfRow row: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    let textDistanceFromTableEdge = 192
    if let cell = tableView.make(withIdentifier: "IncomingMessage", owner: nil) as? IncomingMessage
    {
        cell.message.stringValue = messages[row].message
        let width = ((tableView.tableColumns.last?.width)! - textDistanceFromTableEdge)
        let height = (cell.message.cell!.cellSize(forBounds: NSMakeRect(CGFloat(0.0), CGFloat(0.0), width, CGFloat(FLT_MAX))).height)
        return (height + 50)
    }
}
```

This very often gets the right results, but it's just slightly off (often, when a single word wraps to the next line, it will not result in the cell being one line taller).

Comment: Once a message is in your table view, do you intend to allow the user to edit it?

Comment: First call `drawingRectForBounds` and use the result in `cellSizeForBounds`.

Comment: @PaulPatterson : No. The message won't be edited (it's a chat bubble, like in iMessage/Whatsapp/Facebook).

Comment: @Willeke: would you mind providing a code example to explain exactly what you mean? If it works I can then mark it as the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to ask: will the column housing the messages will be resizable?

Comment: @PaulPatterson Yes: the table is a single column, but as the window is resized the table, and therefore the column, can become wider.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
    let width = self.textField.bounds.width
    let cell = (self.textField.cell() as? NSCell)!
    let rect = cell.drawingRectForBounds(NSMakeRect(CGFloat(0.0), CGFloat(0.0), width, CGFloat(CGFloat.max)))
    let size = cell.cellSizeForBounds(rect)
    self.textField.setFrameSize(NSMakeSize(width, size.height))
```

Similar problem with a different solution: [NSTextFieldCell's cellSizeForBounds: doesn't match wrapping behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356225/nstextfieldcells-cellsizeforbounds-doesnt-match-wrapping-behavior)

Comment: It's *so* very nearly correct but sometimes off. I've no idea why that would be...

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. When resizing my window, sometimes the last word 'i' doesn't fit. Recalculating later fixes it. It feels like the cell isn't ready yet.

Comment: The 'i' isn't working correctly when my text field is being edited.

Comment: Yes, recalculating later does fix it. Gah. No idea what to do here. I think it's just impossible to accurately calculate the height of a wrapping NSTextField in a tableView's heightForRow. Perhaps I should switch to NSTextView...